# Confusion in implementation of C type Switch statement in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement `switch` statement in Python by using dictionary ,but i am getting one problem in that.

Below is what i am trying:

```
print "Enter value of i"
i=eval(raw_input())

j=0
def switch(i):
    print "Hello\n"
    return {True: 'gauw',
            i==1: a(10),
            i==2: a(20),
            }[True]
def a(t):
    global j
    j=t
switch(i)
print j
```

Output:

Enter value of i

1

20

But i am expecting 10 as output.So,here the main problem is that,it is executing both statement for `i==1` & `i==2`. Also,I can't use `break` here.

So how to get desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your switch should be:

```
print "Enter value of i"
i=eval(raw_input())

j=0
def switch(i):
    print "Hello\n"
    try:
        return {
                1: a,
                2: b,
                }[i]()
    except:
        // default action here
        return 'gauw'
def a():
    global j
    j=10
def b():
    global j
    j=20
switch(i)
print j
```

a(10), a(20) are both invoked when the dictionary was built

**EDIT** Adding a default case since there are people who cares about this.

Comment: This will execute `'gauw'()`. The real problem is that both `a(10)` and `a(20)` are executed and do not return any result.

Comment: It's also not giving the desired output,ckeck your code again.

Comment: @user3223301 I am getting 10 for 1 and 20 for 2, these are all the cases you're giving. What is your output?

Comment: The OP's `switch` returns `'gauw'` by default (when `i` is not 1 or 2).

Comment: @JanneKarila The OP's switch return 'gauw' always not just default.

Comment: No, if `i==1` or `i==2` evaluates to `True`, the `True` key is overwritten (with `None` value returned from `a`) in the original code.

Comment: @JanneKarila Oh, That is the case, didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Y do you complicate yourself? If its just the implementation of switch, use if and elif.

```
def switch(i):
    if i==1:
        a(10)
    elif i==2: #Even if here wil work, instead of elif
        a(20)
    else:
        return 'gauw'()
```

Will do the trick

Comment: +1 For being the most sane approach, but I think the `'gauw'` thing should be the default case, i.e., `else: return 'gauw'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate actions from logic, something like this:

```
action_dict = dict([
    (1, lambda: a(10)),
    (2, lambda: a(20)),
    ])

def switch(value, actions):
    if value in actions:
        return actions[value]()
    return 'gauw'

print "Enter value of i"
i=eval(raw_input())

switch(i, action_dict)
```